# Steel frame sets compatible with disc brakes

Tags: frames, hydraulic-disc-brake

I have acquired a shimano deore groupset from a Kona Dew FS. The alu frame snapped due to poor storage whilst in transit. I’d like to fit the components to a new frame set but am interested to hear if anyone knows of some steel frame sets that aren’t the big names (and prices) I.e. Genesis and surly. I need a medium size, 68mm bottom bracket, disc mounts, threadless headset, room for 700c wheels. Any advice welcome.

Comment: Unfortunately, the title change doesn’t address the fundamental problem with the question. It’s not an inherently bad question, but it doesn’t fit the site (read our FAQ, please). You could ask in chat - top right button, click the chat link by current community. Or on a different Internet forum.